# How to use Cloud Foundry Service Broker on localhost

Tags: rabbitmq, cloud-foundry

I have RabbitMQ Service Broker in Cloud Foundry up and running.How can I connect to this service broker from localhost.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly are you trying to do? Are you trying to get to the RMQ management dashboard? Or are you trying to use RMQ broker service outside of cloud foundry?

You mentioned `localhost`. I am assuming you just want to access the RMQ instance.

Do `cf env <app-name>`, where the 'app-name' is the app that you bound the RMQ instance too. This will get you the full url to the RMQ dashboard. You can use to write a test script to add test data to your queues etc.

All this, assuming you are trying to do this in a non-prod environment and you have space developer or admin access to the cloud foundry foundation.

If that does not help, please elaborate more on your requirement.

Comment: I am trying to use RMQ broker service outside the cloud foundry and use it on local host